# Can I get USER/PWD for MYSQL from WINDOWS SERVER

Tags: sql-server, windows

I 'v been trying to get user/pwd for a database in a Windows server.

Server is using : Microsoft SQL server management studio - 2017

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17213.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        14.0.1016.232
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.18861
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.9600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get an existing password since only a hash is stored. If you are an administrator on the box, you can [reset the sa password as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004) and then add accounts and/or reset passwords as needed.

Comment: During the initial setup, you provision windows accounts and set the sa password. Follow the steps in the doc link if you can't use one of those accounts.

Comment: We're here to help. Also see [ORDER BY is Required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/).

Comment: @SultanABUASSI, I don't know much about JavaScript/Node.js but I think you can specify two backslashes instead of one so that it's not treated like an escape character.